# $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z^{4}-1)}\,dz$

Tags: residue-calculus, complex-integration

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(z^{4}-1)}\,dz$

$\text{then} \ z=i,-i,-1,1$ are the value. and Do I have to solve all of these residue??

I cannot set which of that is value for residue.

Comment: Yes, you do have, because all of them are first-order poles for the complex function, therefore the principal value integral for your real function is the sum of the residues.
_Hint_: there's a simple way to calculate the residue for that particular function. Remember that the residue is the $(-1)$-th coefficient of the Laurent expansion

Comment: The integral does not exist -  the principal value of the integral does, though, and maybe that's what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either evaluate it with Residues or with the Cauchy principal Value, which may be worth to be written for once.

$$\text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^4-1}\ \text{d}z = \lim_{R\to \infty}\int_{-R}^{+R}\frac{1}{z^4-1}\ \text{d}z$$

The integral is quite easy to evaluate. You can do it!

The result is:

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\arctan(z) + \frac{1}{4}\log\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)\right]_{-R}^{+R}$$

$$\lim_{R\to \infty}\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\arctan(R) - \arctan(-R)\right) + \frac{1}{4}\left[\log\left(\frac{1-R}{1+R}\right) - \log\left(\frac{1-R}{1+R}\right)\right]\right]$$

As $R$ goes to infinity, the arctangent is well defined. The logarithmic team, instead, goes to zero as you may see by computing the limit.

Hence

$$\text{P.V.} \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^4-1}\ \text{d}z = -\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{\pi}{2}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{2}$$

As wanted.

Comment: No, the p.v. is more complicated than that.  The integral $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^4-1}\ \text{d}z$$ has poles at $1$ and $-1$ where it diverges.  So saying "p.v." also specifies a special way of approaching each of those from the two sides in a balanced way.  (This integral converges very well at infinity, so there is no need to use a p.v. convention there.)

Comment: @GEdgar Actually it does not converge in that range (it does not exist as an integral). So either you use residues, or you use the P.V., as Ron Gordon pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

It seems some people misunderstand the principal value (p.v.).  In this case, the principal value integral is
$$
\lim_{a \searrow 0} \left(\int_{-\infty}^{-1-a}\frac{1}{z^4-1}
+\int_{-1+a}^{1-a}\frac{1}{z^4-1}
+\int_{1+a}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{z^4-1}\right)
$$
This is, indeed, $-\pi/2$ as Alan obtained by glossing over the difficulties.

In Alan's calculation, the fact that
$$
\log\left(\frac{1-z}{1+z}\right)
$$
goes to zero at $\pm \infty$ is irrelevant, since it is discontinuous at $1$ and $-1$.